# How could I temporary redirect stdout to a file in a C program?

Tags: c, redirect, stdout

Within my C program, I’d like to temporarly redirect stdout to `/dev/null` (for example). Then,
after writing to `/dev/null`, I’d like to restore stdout. How do I manage this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

On POSIX systems, you can do it as follows:

```c
int bak, new;

fflush(stdout);
bak = dup(1);
new = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
dup2(new, 1);
close(new);

/* your code here ... */

fflush(stdout);
dup2(bak, 1);
close(bak);
```

What you want is not possible in further generality.

Any solution using `freopen` is wrong, as it does not allow you to restore the original `stdout`. Any solution by assignment to `stdout` is wrong, as `stdout` is not an lvalue (it's a macro that expands to an expression of type `FILE *`).

Comment: Don't use dup2. Use close(new) and then dup(1); dup() ensures you'll get the correct descriptor. `If newfd was open, any errors that would have been reported at close()
time, are lost. A careful programmer will not use dup2 without closing
newfd first. `

Comment: @MoraruLilian: I used `dup2` very intentionally. Your comment has the arguments all mixed up versus my code, so I can't be sure what your point is, but any solution without `dup2` has **dangerous race conditions**. The point of `dup2(x,y)` is to replace `y` **atomically** with a copy of `x`.

Comment: If you are in search of a way to write to a new file and you're like me and haven't memorized all the args to `open`, change the `open` line to `newFd = open(filename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR );`