# Python readline module prints escape character during import

Tags: python, import, stdout, readline, io-redirection

I am using the `readline` module with Python 2.7.3 with Fedora 17. I do not have this problem with Ubuntu 12.10.

During `import readline`, an escape char is displayed.

```bsh
$ python -c 'import readline' |less
ESC[?1034h(END)
```

Usually when I get unexpected output like this, I handle it using `stdout/stderr` redirection to a dummy file descriptor (example below). But this time, this method does not work.

```py
import sys

class DummyOutput(object):
    def write(self, string):
        pass

class suppress_output(object):
    """Context suppressing stdout/stderr output.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout = DummyOutput()
        sys.stderr = DummyOutput()
    def __exit__(self, *_):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Begin'
    with suppress_output():
        # Those two print statements have no effect
        # but *import readline* prints an escape char
        print 'Before importing'
        import readline
        print 'After importing'
    # This one will be displayed
    print 'End'
```

If you run this snippet in a `test.py` script, you will see that inside the `suppress_output` context, the `print` statements are indeed *suppressed*, but not the escape char.

```bsh
$ python test.py |less
Begin
ESC[?1034hEnd
(END)
```

So here are my two questions:

1. How is it possible for this escape character to get through?
2. How to suppress it?

Comment: Looks like the module wants to change the terminal state with an escape sequence but that doesn't work. You shouldn't try to work around that, fix that instead.

Comment: Yes, there is a workaround based on that here http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2009/08/14/readline-invisible-character-hack.html. But this did not answer my first question :) (and I was afraid that was not very portable, but I may be wrong).

Comment: I suspect your terminal and/or terminfo DB cause this problem.

Comment: I think the file descriptor for stdout is always 1. so you can access it directly with for example os.

Comment: I have this problem when ssh-ing to a RedHat machine from my MacBook, and `TERM=xterm-256color`.  I believe it's a readline setup bug.  Best I can do for now is work around it with `export TERM=vt100`.

Comment: related python bug http://bugs.python.org/issue19884

Answer (score 1):

here is what I'm using (admittedly based on @jypeter 's answer), clearing the `TERM` environment variable only if the output does not go to a tty (e.g. is being redirected to a file):

```
if not sys.stdout.isatty():

    # remember the original setting
    oldTerm = os.environ['TERM']

    os.environ['TERM'] = ''

    import readline

    # restore the orignal TERM setting
    os.environ['TERM'] = oldTerm

    del oldTerm
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question: changing `sys.stdout` doesn't actually affect what file [stdout's file descriptor is pointing at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), but instead just what high-level file object Python considers to be stdout. Said another way, changing `sys.stdout` affects your Python code, but not (generally) any compiled extensions you may be using (like the readline module). All this applies to `sys.stderr` as well.

To answer the second: you can do what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832902/3920202) suggests (which should be straightforward to port to Python). Though the suggestions in the comments sound like a better way to go.

Comment: here's [how to redirect stdout at C level in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following hack, before importing readline

```
import os
if os.environ['TERM'] == 'xterm':
    os.environ['TERM'] = 'vt100'
# Now it's OK to import readline :)
import readline
```

Comment: the problem appears also with `xterm-256color`

Comment: but setting `os.environ['TERM'] = ''` then importing `readline` and then restore `os.environ['TERM']` back to what it was before avoids printing the escape sequence (not sure about other functionality of `readline` though...)