# using tee with continuous output of a C program

Tags: c, linux, bash, tee

It must be really simple but I can't catch it.

This is a trivial C program writing to stdout:

```
root@oceanLondon:~/tst# cat tst.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        for (; ;) {
                printf("Hello world!\n");
                sleep(1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Now, if I want to write the output to my screen and a file:

```
root@oceanLondon:~/tst# ./tst |tee file
```

it just do not work, I have empty screen and empty file.

if I do a program that exits, then it perfectly works, e.g.

```
root@oceanLondon:~/tst# ls |tee file
Makefile
file
qq
tst
tst.c
tst.o
root@oceanLondon:~/tst# cat file
Makefile
file
qq
tst
tst.c
tst.o
root@oceanLondon:~/tst#
```

Is it some kind of buffering issue? And can someone help me to do tee on a continues program, please?

Comment: And if you try to `fflush(stdout);`?

Comment: @fredtantini: then it works indeed. Was really simple one. Thanks - feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: There seem to be some useful answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee). (I'm not on a Linux machine right now, so I can't try them out.)

Comment: By the way, I saw once that output of \n (i.e. printf("\n");) would make the flush happened automatically, or do I confuse it with Nagel algorithm?

Comment: This may help: [How could I temporary redirect stdout to a file in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4832603/2455888).

Comment: @fredtantini as the only answer to this question has been deleted, maybe you should post one.

Comment: Standard output is usually line buffered when it goes direct to a terminal.  When it goes to a pipe, it is normally fully buffered.  You can either use `fflush()` in each iteration, or call `setvbuf()` to make standard output line buffered explicitly.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

Answer (score 2):

Standard output stream is line buffered if the stream can be determined to refer to an **interactive device** (eg. terminal), otherwise it's fully buffered, therefore, there are cases where `printf` doesn't flush, even if it has a newline to print, like piped or redirected output;

```
> tst | tee file
> tst > file
```

Calling `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()` will solve the problem.

Related text from `C99` section `7.19.3` states that;

> When a stream is unbuffered, characters are intended to appear from
>   the source or at the destination as soon as possible. Otherwise
>   characters may be accumulated and transmitted to or from the host
>   environment as a block.
>
> When a stream is fully buffered, characters are intended to be
>   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer
>   is filled.
>
> When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be
>   transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line
>   character is encountered.
>
> As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered;
>   the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if
>   and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an
>   interactive device.

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict your quote. (**line buffered** in first sentence of answer, **fully buffered** in last sentence of quote)

Comment: @ace, you are absolutely right, I fixed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is that `stdout` is buffered and isn't displayed after the new line. You can force to display it by flushing it after your printf statement:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Alternatively, you can disable buffering with:

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

Also, note that `stderr` is not buffered, and you can check if the problem is a buffered one by printing to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

As you have noticed, you can also use `stdbuf` (more info with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337109/2550808)).

Comment: if you edit your answer to include this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11337109/2550808 I will accept it