# temporary redirect stderr to null on windows platform within a c code.

Tags: c, windows, redirect, stderr

I need the equivalent of this for the windows platform, any pointers please ?
This is what I have followed for *nix platforms and it seems to be working so far.The link can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832603/how-could-i-temporary-redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-a-c-program)

Comment: It should be similar for Windows, but you have to `#include <io.h>` and should use `_dup` instead of `dup`, `_dup2` instead of `dup2`, etc.

Comment: Oh, and you need to open `"nul"` instead of `"/dev/null"`.

Answer (score 1):

As a more extensible alternative, consider declaring a variable (you could call it `error_stream`?) which at times you have set to `stderr`, and at other times you have set to some other file (e.g. `fopen(NUL_DEVICE_FILENAME, "wb");` on Windows NT).

One nice aspect of this code is you can change `NUL_DEVICE_FILENAME` (or even the entire functions) to suit each OS; the functions become an interface to make *less portable* behaviour easier to port. See test.c (near the bottom of this post) for example usage, and the output below that as proof that it works. Best of luck with this snippet... :)

error_stream.h:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_ERROR_STREAM
#define INCLUDE_ERROR_STREAM
#include <stdio.h>

FILE  *get_error_stream(void);
void   set_error_stream(FILE *);
void reset_error_stream(void);
void blank_error_stream(void);
#endif
```

---

error_stream.c:

```
#include "error_stream.h"
#define NUL_DEVICE_FILENAME "NUL" /* This worked fine for me on Win10 */
                                  /* Try "\\Device\\Null", "NUL" and  *
                                   *  ... "NUL:" if it doesn't work,  *
                                   *  ... or obviously "/dev/null" on *
                                   *  ... *nix                        */
FILE *error_stream, *blank_stream;
FILE *get_error_stream(void) {
    if (!error_stream) {
        error_stream = stderr;
    }
    return error_stream;
}
void set_error_stream(FILE *f) {
    error_stream = f;
}
void reset_error_stream(void) {
    set_error_stream(stderr);
}
void blank_error_stream(void) {
    if (!blank_stream) {
        blank_stream = fopen(NUL_DEVICE_FILENAME, "wb+");
    }
    set_error_stream(blank_stream);
}
```

---

test.c:

```
#include "error_stream.h"
int main(void) {
    fputs("Testing\n", get_error_stream());
    blank_error_stream();

    fputs("Testing\n", get_error_stream());
    reset_error_stream();

    fputs("One\n", get_error_stream());
    blank_error_stream();

    fputs("Two\n", get_error_stream());
    reset_error_stream();
}
```

---

```
C:\Users\Seb\Desktop>gcc -c error_stream.c -o error_stream.o
C:\Users\Seb\Desktop>gcc test.c error_stream.o -o test.exe
C:\Users\Seb\Desktop>test
Testing
One
```